# Perform simple regression without raw data

Tags: regression

I have a dataset that I can collect some quantities from, eg. sum,mean,variance...
I want to perform a simple regression on column(x,y). According to Wikipedia, the closed form for $\alpha,\beta$ is

\begin{equation}
\alpha=\frac{Cov(x,y)}{Var(x)}
\quad \mbox{and} \quad 
\beta=\bar{y}-\beta\bar{x}.
\end{equation}

However I would also like some more stats from the regression, for example **r, r-square, significance...**

Basically I want to get the same result that this [apache SimpleRegression](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math/stat/regression/SimpleRegression.html) class produces by only feeding collected quantities instead of raw data points. Any advice on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard regression textbook would give the formulas to convert between the different quantities (r is just covariance divided by the 2 standard deviations, r-squared is just r squared, the F statistic for only 1 x in the model is r/(1-r)/(n-2), etc.)

Writing a function that will do all of this automatically is on my to do list, but does not exist yet.

A simple alternative is to simulate data from a bivariate (or multivariate) normal that matches your summaries, then just run the regression on the simulated data.  The mvrnorm function in the MASS package for R will simulate such data, set empirical=TRUE.